# Spring BeanDefinitionParsingException

Tags: spring-mvc

i am getting the following error below:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:
>   Configuration problem: Unable to
>   locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML
>   schema namespace
>   [http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc]
>   Offending resource: ServletContext
>   resource
>   [/WEB-INF/raceLeague-servlet.xml]
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1294)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:92)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:507)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
>     org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
>     org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
>     org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
>     org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:402)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:316)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:282)
>     org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:126)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)
>     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown
>   Source)

Im not too sure why but im guessing somethings wrong with my servlett.xml? below is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

        <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.jr" />


</beans>
```

The Spring library i am using is from here http://www.springsource.com/download/community . i saw two sets of jar files. one in dist folder and one in src folder. i used the jar files in the dist folder and added it to my WEB-INF/lib folder.

here is my lib folder:

```
28/02/2005  16:32           999,966 ant-1.6.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             5,659 ant-antlr-1.6.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            73,665 ant-junit-1.6.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             8,673 ant-launcher-1.6.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             6,755 ant-swing-1.6.2.jar

18/08/2010  11:36           443,432 antlr-2.7.6.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             1,221 antlr.license.txt

29/11/2009  23:03           345,048 apache-mime4j-0.6.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            11,358 apache.license-2.0.txt

28/02/2005  16:32             2,660 apache.license.txt

28/02/2005  16:32           397,997 c3p0-0.8.5.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            26,430 c3p0.license.txt

13/09/2010  13:54           322,362 cglib-nodep-2.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           142,704 cleanimports.jar

30/07/2010  11:51           232,019 commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar

29/11/2009  23:02            46,725 commons-codec-1.3.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           175,426 commons-collections-2.1.1.jar

18/08/2010  11:36           559,366 commons-collections-3.1.jar

30/07/2010  11:48           575,389 commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

07/02/2010  11:56           707,465 commons-dbcp-1.4-javadoc.jar

07/02/2010  11:55           159,513 commons-dbcp-1.4-sources.jar

07/02/2010  11:52           160,519 commons-dbcp-1.4.jar

23/09/2010  09:10            59,590 commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar

23/09/2010  09:10           109,043 commons-io-1.4.jar

30/07/2010  11:35           279,193 commons-lang-2.5.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            38,015 commons-logging-1.0.4.jar

01/11/2009  14:58            60,686 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
30/07/2010  10:27            60,841 commons-logging.jar


12/11/2009  19:43           436,817 commons-pool-1.5.4-javadoc.jar

12/11/2009  19:43            96,194 commons-pool-1.5.4-sources.jar

12/11/2009  19:38            96,221 commons-pool-1.5.4.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           171,071 concurrent-1.3.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            17,978 connector.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             9,790 connector.licence.txt

28/02/2005  16:32           312,509 dom4j-1.5.2.jar

18/08/2010  11:36           313,898 dom4j-1.6.1.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            47,531 ehcache-1.1.jar

30/07/2010  11:42            86,487 ezmorph-1.0.6.jar

27/05/2010  16:38           100,884 hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final

11/06/2009  17:35         2,220,643 hibernate3.jar

03/12/2009  22:43           291,039 httpclient-4.0.1.jar

29/11/2009  23:05           172,888 httpcore-4.0.1.jar

03/12/2009  22:43            25,443 httpmime-4.0.1.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           104,359 jaas.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             9,863 jaas.licence.txt

28/02/2005  16:32            24,180 jacc-1_0-fr.jar

18/08/2010  11:36           597,476 javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           239,006 jaxen-1.1-beta-4.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           342,872 jboss-cache.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           389,484 jboss-common.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           588,329 jboss-jmx.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           165,248 jboss-remoting.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           215,223 jboss-system.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             6,727 jdbc2_0-stdext.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             7,932 jdbc2_0-stdext.licence.txt

28/02/2005  16:32         1,652,084 jgroups-2.2.7.jar

30/07/2010  09:42           151,390 json-lib-2.3-jdk13.jar

30/07/2010  11:39           151,839 json-lib-2.3-jdk15.jar

30/07/2010  11:58           414,240 jstl-1.2.jar

18/08/2010  11:47            10,899 jta-1.1.jar

28/02/2005  16:32             8,812 jta.jar


28/02/2005  16:32             9,830 jta.licence.txt

28/02/2005  16:32           121,070 junit-3.8.1.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           352,291 log4j-1.2.9.jar


10/09/2010  16:12           236,079 mysql-connector-java-3.0.16-ga-bi

10/09/2010  16:12           391,434 mysql-connector-java-3.1.6-bin.ja

23/06/2010  16:38           767,492 mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.j

20/10/2010  16:21           321,190 org.springframework.aop-3.0.5.REL

20/10/2010  16:21            53,082 org.springframework.asm-3.0.5.REL

20/10/2010  16:21            35,548 org.springframework.aspects-3.0.5
r
20/10/2010  16:21           555,410 org.springframework.beans-3.0.5.R

20/10/2010  16:21           668,861 org.springframework.context-3.0.5
r
20/10/2010  16:21           100,870 org.springframework.context.suppo
LEASE.jar
20/10/2010  16:21           382,442 org.springframework.core-3.0.5.RE

20/10/2010  16:21           169,752 org.springframework.expression-3.
.jar
20/10/2010  16:21             1,810 org.springframework.instrument-3.
.jar
20/10/2010  16:21             5,728 org.springframework.instrument.to
RELEASE.jar
20/10/2010  16:21           385,712 org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.5.RE

20/10/2010  16:21           185,312 org.springframework.jms-3.0.5.REL

20/10/2010  16:21           334,327 org.springframework.orm-3.0.5.REL

20/10/2010  16:21            61,379 org.springframework.oxm-3.0.5.REL

20/10/2010  16:21           205,278 org.springframework.test-3.0.5.RE

20/10/2010  16:21           231,922 org.springframework.transaction-3
E.jar
20/10/2010  16:21           395,587 org.springframework.web-3.0.5.REL
20/10/2010  16:21           175,412 org.springframework.web.portlet-3

E.jar
20/10/2010  16:21           418,977 org.springframework.web.servlet-3
E.jar
20/10/2010  16:21            31,404 org.springframework.web.struts-3.
.jar
28/02/2005  16:32           114,308 oscache-2.1.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           475,943 proxool-0.8.3.jar

28/02/2005  16:30             2,862 README.txt

27/05/2010  11:29            22,338 slf4j-api-1.5.6.jar

18/08/2010  11:26            23,445 slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar

27/05/2010  11:30             9,678 slf4j-log4j12-1.5.6.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           325,942 spring-aop.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           488,282 spring-beans.jar

31/10/2008  17:25            96,880 spring-context-support.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           476,940 spring-context.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           285,491 spring-core.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           335,484 spring-jdbc.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           195,350 spring-jms.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           377,805 spring-orm.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           180,924 spring-test.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           231,173 spring-tx.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           194,577 spring-web.jar
31/10/2008  17:25           149,683 spring-webmvc-portlet.jar

31/10/2008  17:25            36,748 spring-webmvc-struts.jar

31/10/2008  17:25           402,396 spring-webmvc.jar

31/10/2008  17:25         2,949,500 spring.jar

28/02/2005  16:32            30,602 swarmcache-1.0rc2.jar

27/05/2010  11:29            47,433 validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

28/02/2005  16:30             4,538 version.properties

28/02/2005  16:32             5,762 versioncheck.jar

28/02/2005  16:32         1,010,806 xerces-2.6.2.jar

28/02/2005  16:32           123,705 xml-apis.jar
```

web.xml file here as well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>

        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <!-- index.htm web page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.jsp
    </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Register and setup my servlet xml files here -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>raceLeague</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>raceLeague</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Here is my build script too:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="Online Racing League" basedir="." default="usage">
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
    <property name="web.dir" value="war"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <property name="name" value="Online Racing League"/>

    <path id="master-classpath">
        <fileset dir="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <!-- We need the servlet API classes: -->
        <!--  * for Tomcat 5/6 use servlet-api.jar -->
        <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
        <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
            <include name="servlet*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="usage">
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="${name} build file"/>
        <echo message="-----------------------------------"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="Available targets are:"/>
        <echo message=""/>
        <echo message="build     --> Build the application"/>
        <echo message="deploy    --> Deploy application as directory"/>
        <echo message="deploywar --> Deploy application as a WAR file"/>
        <echo message="install   --> Install application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="reload    --> Reload application in Tomcat"/>
        <echo message="start     --> Start Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="stop      --> Stop Tomcat application"/>
        <echo message="list      --> List Tomcat applications"/>
        <echo message=""/>
    </target>

    <target name="build" description="Compile main source tree java files">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac destdir="${build.dir}" source="1.5" target="1.5" debug="true"
               deprecation="false" optimize="false" failonerror="true">
            <src path="${src.dir}"/>
            <classpath refid="master-classpath"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="build" description="Deploy application">
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}/${name}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>

    <target name="deploywar" depends="build" description="Deploy application as a WAR file">
        <war destfile="${deploy.path}/${name}.war"
             webxml="${web.dir}/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="${web.dir}">
                <include name="**/*.*"/>
            </fileset>
        </war>
        <copy todir="${deploy.path}" preservelastmodified="true">
            <fileset dir=".">
                <include name="*.war"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>



    <!-- ============================================================== -->
    <!-- Tomcat tasks - remove these if you don't have Tomcat installed -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

        <path id="catalina-ant-classpath">
            <!-- We need the Catalina jars for Tomcat -->
            <!--  * for other app servers - check the docs -->
            <fileset dir="${appserver.lib}">
                <include name="catalina-ant.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </path>

        <taskdef name="install" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>
        <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask">
            <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
        </taskdef>

        <target name="install" description="Install application in Tomcat">
            <install url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"
                     war="${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="reload" description="Reload application in Tomcat">
            <reload url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="start" description="Start Tomcat application">
            <start url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="stop" description="Stop Tomcat application">
            <stop url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"
                     path="/${name}"/>
        </target>

        <target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
            <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
                     username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
                     password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
        </target>

    <!-- End Tomcat tasks -->

    </project>
```

build.properties file below:

```
# Ant properties for building the springapp

appserver.home=C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0
# for Tomcat 5 use $appserver.home}/server/lib
# for Tomcat 6 use $appserver.home}/lib
appserver.lib=${appserver.home}/lib/

deploy.path=${appserver.home}/webapps

tomcat.manager.url=http://localhost:8080/manager
tomcat.manager.username=
tomcat.manager.password=
```

Comment: Are you sure that the spring-mvc jar is on the classpath?

Comment: The  spring 3 i downloaded from the link above did not contain a spring-mvc jar. all it contained were a bunch of org.springframework.xxx.3.0.5.RELEASE files no mvc. did i download the correct files?

Comment: Holy creeping jeppers, that's a lot of libraries. You really need to do some trimming, rather than just dumping world+dog in there.

Answer (score 3):

The Spring download bundle contains the Spring framework separated into multiple modules, spring-core, spring-beans etc. One of them is org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar.

This jar contains the xsd for the mvc schema. Can you confirm it is on your classpath?

EDIT:

Looks as though you have multiple copies of Spring in your lib dir. You have some jars from Spring 2 in there. Remove any of the spring jars that don't start with org.springframework.... 
e.g. spring.jar, spring-mvc.jar

While you're at it, there are a bunch of other jars that you don't need in there. You have multiple copies of common-dbcp, commons-collections, commons-pool, dom4j. You have Ant jars and Junit jars in there. You might come across other errors at runtime if you don't clean out the duplicates.

Comment: Yea i can confirm its in my classpath. i added via eclipse using the projects properties

Comment: Can you describe your setup? Are you launching Tomcat from Eclipse or directly? Is the jar in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your WAR?

Comment: i installed tomcat 7 using the setup.exe app from apache and launched it from the tomcat monitor app that gets installed on my machine. Yes the jar is directly inside my lib directory inside my war. i will list libs that are in my war file on the original post

Comment: Hi Kevin, i removed all the spring.jar files and still did not resolve my issue :( i double checked on both file explorer and on the projects properties in eclipse to make sure its removed and it was. let me post my web.xml file too

Comment: How are you creating and deploying the WAR to Tomcat? Do you have an Ant build script? If so, could you post that too.

Comment: edit: saw your new edit. i will remove all jars except the spring stuff and start from there. those jars i used on a spring 2.5 project i did before and i needed most of those to get it working.

Comment: ANy other suggestions? i tried cleaning up my libs folder and still could not get it to work

Comment: Are you deploying to Tomcat? It could be that there are Spring jars in a shared lib directory. Try installing a clean Tomcat instance and then deploying just your war into it. Can you also post the contents of your WEB-INF/lib dir now that you have cleaned it up.